# SwiftMailer does not send mail, why?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

SwiftMail does not send my email, while `mail()` does work. Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552937/swiftmailer-wont-send-mail-but-mail-will).

I added the EchoLogger but it does not print anything.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('Test');
$message->setTo( $email );
$message->setFrom(ABSENDER);
$message->setBody($nl_text);

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

$result = $mailer->send($message, $failures);
var_dump($failures);
```

The email is returned in `$failures` but why?

**Update**

In `Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker::mail` I dumped out the parameters and got this:

```
  $headers =>
  string(208) "Message-ID: <1337173064.4fb3a4480b8dd@domain.de>
Date: Wed, 16 May 2012 14:57:44 +0200
From: news@domain.de
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
"
  $extraParams =>
  string(15) "-fnews@domain.de"
```

`$to, $subject, $body` is same as I used in `mail()`. Still no idea what the problem is.

**Update #2**

This worked fine for me:

```
mail($email, 'Test', $nl_text, "From: " . ABSENDER);
```

**Disclaimer**: This is not a solution but the workaround I used, because I did not have the time to debugger the framework and find a real solution. Feel free to use the information given above to debug yourself and post your solution here. I will gladly accept and upvote it.

Comment: Could you get a solution to this ?

Comment: My solution was to replace it with a simple `mail($email, 'Anmeldung', $nl_text, "From: " . ABSENDER);` but it does not solve the problem so I got down votes and finally deleted my answer. The problem would require some debugging but I did not had the time for that.

Comment: Nice, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.

According to the documentation [swiftmailer.org](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) by default Swift_MailTransport::newInstance() uses parameters `-f%s` and that is why you got `"-fnews@domain.de"`, to solve that place blank space between `-f %s`.

Your code now can be looks like that:
`$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('-f %s')`;

I solved that problem simply passing `null` to __construct(). So my working code looks like that:

`$message = Swift_Message::newInstance(null)`;

I hope it will help someone.

P.S. I use Postfix to send emails.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use the debugger and step to through the code behind send().

If you can not use a debugger you should have a look at the function `mail` in `lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SimpleMailInvoker.php`. There is a call to the internal mail function with an shutup operator (´@´). Maybe removing this operator can show you an error message. Also you can use `var_dump()` to dump the parameters passed there.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix it. I was using noReply@mydomain.com in from header and this email account was not created. I created noReply@mydomain.com and my emails started working. I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Interestingly, this worked for me. An in-existent email address in the from field won't be delivered

Comment: Yes - (long time Swift user here)  VERY annoying it fails with no error without a valid "reply to"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using the default transport mechanism which [according to their docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-mail-transport) uses `mail()` by default.

Serious drawbacks when using this Transport are :

- Unpredictable message headers
- **Lack of feedback regarding delivery failures**
- Lack of support for several plugins that require real-time delivery feedback

[source](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-mail-transport)

If I were debugging this, I would find SwiftMailer's implementation of the `mail()` function and dump the arguments it's passing and compare them to your own working version of `mail()`. I don't have any experience with SwiftMailer but this seems like a fast option.

Comment: I did that (see update). Still I think I go with using mail directly. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: You've eliminated the possibility of the culprit being in $to, $subject, or $body. Use the exact-same headers that SwiftMailer produced (you SHOULD NOT receive the email). Then, one by one remove each header and re-test until you find the header or headers that are causing it to fail. Repeat with $extraParams if necessary. From there you'll know what the specific problem is and have the ability to search for a better solution than `mail()` :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `Swift_Transport_MailTransport, private $_extraParams = '-f%s'`.

The flag `'-f'` (see your code: `string(15) "-fnews@domain.de"`) will fail in some situations. Code Igniter has the same "bug".

Comment: Thanks, can you add mote information? When does it fail? Link to Code Igniter bug, ... Right now this does not explain what the problem is nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out on symfony if I just exit the function with "exit()" for example, swiftmailer won't send the mail but if I ended with

return new Response(); it sends fine. so I am not sure.

Comment: From what I recall, the mail is queued, and sent only on kernel termination. So this is normal.

Answer (score -2):

This may be really old, Had the same problem i solved it when using a **shorter** *from* email. seems like the maximum length after the @ sign is 10. that is what i have tested so far.

example:

```
$sname = 'noreply@system.com';
->setFrom(array($sname => 'Some Header Title here'));
```